# How to strip off piece of text from a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following String text:

`/Return/ReturnData/IRS1040/DependentWorksheetPP[1]/DependentCodePP`

I'd like to strip off the `[1]` index so I just have:

`/Return/ReturnData/IRS1040/DependentWorksheetPP/DependentCodePP`

How can I accomplish this in Java?

`string.replaceAll("[?]","");`

This doesn't seem to work.

Any help or info would be much appreciated

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, 'replaceAll' will return a new string that has the replacements. See [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951333/why-isnt-the-string-value-changed-after-string-replace-in-java. Is this the issue you're having?

Comment: Replace `\[\d+\]` by empty string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in Java, `String` is immutable (so be sure to assign the result of `replaceAll`). Next, the `[` and `]` are meaningful in a regular expression (escape them). And `\\d+` is one or more digit. Something like,

```
String str = "/Return/ReturnData/IRS1040/DependentWorksheetPP[1]/"
    + "DependentCodePP";
str = str.replaceAll("\\[\\d+\\]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
/Return/ReturnData/IRS1040/DependentWorksheetPP/DependentCodePP
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]","");
```

You need to escape `[]` as they are special characters in regex.